# $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h} f(s)ds$ Need some hint to approach this problem.

Tags: real-analysis

How do we approach to solve question of this type. I just need some hint. I will try to solve it on my own.

$f$ is a continuous from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h} f(s)ds$$

Comment: What's the context? What's $f$? Does $\mathrm ds$ has any other meaning?

Comment: Got this question from a Facebook maths age. Honestly I don't know. Most probably it was asked in some scholarship exam. @xbh

Comment: Then this is simple, either L'Hôpital or MVT of integrals.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?  Or testing out various cases with small $h$ ?

Comment: Split the integral into two using the point $t$ and then by fundamental theorem of calculus the answer $2f(t)$ is immediate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not require any theorem. Just use definition of continuity: $\frac 1 h \int_{t-h}^{t+h} f(x)\, dx -2f(t)=\frac 1 h \int_{t-h}^{t+h} [f(x)-f(t)]\, dx$ and now you can use the fact that $|f(x)-f(t)| <\epsilon$ for $|x-t|$ is sufficeintly small.

Comment: This is good.  In particular, it still works if $f$ is continuous at the point $t$ but not anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hospital rule and solve the equation as :
Let $f(s)$ be a function.Then $$f'(s) = lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(t+h)+f(t-h)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s) \,ds}{h}$$ which will be equal to $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(t+h)+f(t-h)}{1} \\$$
which is $$= 2f(t)$$

The case is valid when $f$ is continuous.

Comment: $f$ might not be continuous.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @xbh function is continuous. I have edited the post. Sorry.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician : if the solution cleared your doubt  don't forget to accept the solution :)

Comment: @ItiShree Can you explain how do we differentiate something involving integral. Are we using  the fundamental theorem of calculus here.

Comment: We are using L'Hsopital rule as $lim_{h \to 0}$ so the whole function will tend to $\infty$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: @ItiShree I know the rule. I am asking how are we calculating $\frac{d}{dh}$ of numerator?

Comment: @StammeringMathematician : added , also see definiton of Definition (Derivative ) -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Differentiation/Differentiation_Defined

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the value of the limit.

By mean value theorem, there exist $t-h\le c\le t+h$ such that the right limit equals to
$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{2h\cdot f(c)}{h}=2f\left(\lim_{h\to 0^+}c\right)=2f(t)$$
by squeeze theorem.

Suppose the required limit exists, then I can obtain $L$ by approaching from any direction, so $$L=2f(t)$$